# How To Declare Input-Output Parameters In SQL Server Stored Procedure/Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, function, stored-procedures

In Oracle,

We can declare an input-output parameters (not just input **or** output) like the following:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure USERTEST.SimpleInOutProcedure(
    p_InputInt Int,
    p_OutputInt out Int,
    p_InputOutputInt in out Int
) AS
BEGIN
    p_OutputInt := p_InputInt + 1;
    p_InputOutputInt := p_InputOutputInt + p_InputOutputInt;
END;
```

However, as I try to declare such in SQL Server, the script would not compile:

```
create procedure SimpleInOutProcedure 
    @p_InputInt int, @p_OutputInt int input output
As
Begin
    Select * from TestTableCommonA;
End
```

The word "input" is not expected, thus not blue-colored in the SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

What's wrong with my script, how to declare input-output parameters in SQL Server Stored Procedure/Function?

I want to do this because I need to create "equivalent" reader for SQL Server DB which previously was created for Oracle DB and has the reader for in/out parameters.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you declare a parameter as OUTPUT, it acts as Both Input and OUTPUT

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SimpleInOutProcedure 
(
    @p_InputInt  INT,
    @p_OutputInt INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       @p_OutputInt = @p_OutputInt
END
GO

DECLARE @p_OutputInt int = 4
EXEC SimpleInOutProcedure @p_InputInt = 1, @p_OutputInt = @p_OutputInt OUTPUT
SELECT @p_OutputInt
```

Comment: This is what I suspect too... but, is there any explicit documentation about this? because I cannot find an explicit documentation about this since I do not want to miss any equivalent as long as it is possible to do so, especially on the *both* input-output behavior part. (I didn't know that it will act as both input and output though, I thought it would be *either* input or output).

Comment: I don't have any documentation. But this does not looks like needed a detailed documentation

Comment: Ok, let me test your script for a while

Comment: Yes, it seems like @p_OutputInt acts as both input and output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is sample code for SQL Input & Output parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample_Insert]
@name varchar(500),
@entryby int,
@RetVal INT = 0 OUT

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON



INSERT INTO dbo.Master
        ( name ,
          entry_date ,
          entry_by
        )
VALUES  ( @name , -- service_name - varchar(1000)
          dbo.GetActDate() , -- entry_date - datetime
          @entryby  -- entry_by - int
        )




IF @@ERROR =  0
BEGIN
SET @RetVal = 1 -- 1 IS FOR SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED
End
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @RetVal = 0 -- 0 WHEN AN ERROR HAS OCCURED
End

 set ANSI_NULLS ON
 set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! It won't help much though since what I want to know is if there is equivalent for input-output in SQL Server