# How do I specify parameter "output only" direction in a stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The situation: I am using Allen-Bradley (Rockwell) software package known as FactoryTalk Transaction Manager, which allows PLC's to use the power of SQL Server to do things.

Using SQL Server 2012, I need to specify the direction of parameters within the stored procedure, which I incorrectly assumed was as simple as an

```
@QuarantineReason nvarchar(256) OUTPUT
```

However when viewed in the Object Explorer of SSMS the properties for the stored procedure parameter shows

```
@QuarantineReason (nvarchar(256), Input/Output, No default)
```

In order to simplify my life greatly, I would like the parameter to be an output only, as this saves me binding the input side of things in the Allen-Bradley software.

I found several MS documentation resources online but they all seem to specify C# as the codebase, which is bewildering to me.

[SqlParameter.Direction Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[Input, Output and Input/Output SqlParameter Behavior Explained](https://contrivedexample.com/2016/10/22/input-output-and-inputoutput-sqlparameter-behavior-explained/)

[Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: AFAIK there is no Output Only option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Declare Input-Output Parameters In SQL Server Stored Procedure/Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129536/how-to-declare-input-output-parameters-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-function)

Comment: There is no such thing as an output-only parameter in T-SQL; it is always possible to pass an input value, and this value will be available to the code. Client code that treats such a parameter as "output only" simply doesn't specify an value when calling the procedure. Unless, of course, it doesn't know about this T-SQL quirk, as appears to be the case here. Consider giving the parameter an explicit but unused dummy default (`@QuarantineReason NVARCHAR(256) OUTPUT = NULL`); the software might detect this and allow you to omit the input binding.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please answer with your comment, and I will accept it as the most relevant answer.  It is very clear and addresses the client software and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that in MSSQL, and you would have to specify the direction **when calling the SP** (as well as in the parameter declaration of the SP itself).

The documentation you found with C# examples is for calling an MSSQL SP from .NET C# code.

Hope this helps.