# Stored procedure output variable being stored as input/output type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to get the metadata for a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server using the Java SQL API.

This is the structure of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testproc] 
    (@rolloverType AS integer,
     @retval nvarchar(50) output)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @retval = [col1]
    FROM [dbo].[Table_1]
    WHERE col3 = @rolloverType;
END
GO
```

However, the Java SQL API is saying that `@retval` is an `INOUT` type, and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio also shows this parameter as an `Input/Output` type. How can I construct this stored procedure so that `@retval` is only of type `Output`?

Comment: There are no output-only parameters in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GSerg commented, you can't.

In SQL, an `OUTPUT` parameter acts as both `INPUT` and `OUTPUT`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129796/11725816)

You're obtaining an `INOUT` value because of the mapping used to refer ORACLE procedure parameter types, which are `IN`, `OUT` and `INOUT`.

From [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_easyoracle_pl_sql_in_out_inout_modes.htm):

> A variable passed as mode `IN` is always read-only.  A variable
>   using `IN` mode can be read and used by the procedure/function but can
>   not be changed and it cannot be the receiver of an assignment
>   operation.
>
> A variable passed in `OUT` mode is used to pass information back from
>   the procedure to the calling program.  It is a write-only variable and
>   has no value until the block assigns it a value.
>
> A variable passed in `INOUT` mode has characteristics of both the `IN` and
>   the `OUT` mode.  The variable value is passed in and can be read by the
>   procedure.  The procedure can also change the value and it will be
>   copied back to the passed variable when the procedure completes.

Answer (score -2):

If Management Studio sees `@retval` as `OUTPUT`, you will be able to read this value from outside. The fact that `@retval` is also marked as Input is irrelevant.

Comment: Its not irrelevant when you have Java code that is checking for whether or not its of type `INOUT` or just `OUT`